# Get data from header file into non-member function in source file

Tags: c++, header-files

I have a data like BigArr, arr, ... declared in header:

```
class TableView:public QWidget 
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:TableView (QWidget * parent = 0);

  std::vector < TXdata >  BigArr;

  std::vector < float >  arr;
  std::vector < float >  arr2;
  std::vector < int >  arrlocKtab;
  std::vector < int >  arrlocKrow;
```

In source file I have some functions I copy/pasted from somewhere else, like:

```
static void
 multiply (float q[4], float value)
{
  q[0] *= value;
  q[1] *= value;
  q[2] *= value;
  q[3] *= value;
}
```

and some other functions I made, like:

```
 void
 TableView::ShowContextMenu (const QPoint & pos)    // this is a slot
 {
```

How do I get declarations from header file to work inside copy/pasted functions. Like:

```
  static void
     multiply (float q[4], float value)
    {

  arr[0]= something...
```

I got some bad results from renaming c/p functions to void TableView::function and adding them to function list in the header file. Probably something to do with the static void &static inline void... Ty

Comment: What were the bad results you got? It would be helpful to see them.

Comment: As i remember it was something about a call to the non-static function inside the c/p function. Do i have to change every function call to TableView::function or ?

Comment: ok, then both answers below solve the problem. I think @Als and I answered/edited at about the same time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the multiply function as part of the TableView class as follows:

```
class TableView:public QWidget 
{
    ...
    void multiply(float q[4], float value);
    ...
};
```

Then define it in the source file like this:

```
void TableView::multiply(float q[4], float value)
{
    ...
    arr[0] = something;
    ...
}
```

Or you pass an instance of TableView into multiply() if you cant/dont want to make it a member of TableView. If you decide to pass in an instance of TableView to the function, then you'll have to consider how to access the class members, either by making a getter function or making them public. The getter acccessor function is a cleaner solution.

Either way will work, but if you decide to make everything member functions, consider the design and make sure the class doesnt become bloated, called low cohesion: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: Ok, I will change everything to member functions. So do I have to put static void /static inline void thing only in a header and only void in source file, or just use void on every void related function? ty both!

Comment: Either way will work, but if you decide to make everything member functions, consider the design and make sure the class doesnt become bloated, called low cohesion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: Ok, I changed the code like I said I will. Now I get this link error:

Error 102 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl sortd(int,float *,int *)" (?sortd@@YAXHPEAMPEAH@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl TableView::jacobi(float (* const)[4],float (* const)[4],float * const,int * const,int *,int *,float *)" (?jacobi@TableView@@AEAAXQEAY03M0QEAMQEAHPEAH3PEAM@Z) M:\Lecad2\TremeshBuild\src\Tremesh\TableView.obj

Any ideas why?

Comment: Its really hard to see that in a comment, maybe you could put it on ideone.com and paste the link here. Or at least on pastebin.com. Is this Windows?

Comment: @user1220769, where is sortId() defined? If its defined in a different source file/object file, then make sure you link it in also.

Comment: I solved it! Compiles ok now.  it was this line of code inside one of the c/p functions: //void sortd (int, float *, int *); /* black box sorting routine */ . Guess somebody copypaste the method and forgot to delete it, and somehow it compiled before and doesn't with TableView::?